# Wsimport throws NoClassDefFoundError: LocalizableMessageFactory

Tags: java, wsimport

I need to execute wsimport (Java 8) on my Mac and it fails with this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/internal/ws/util/localization/LocalizableMessageFactory
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.resources.WscompileMessages.<clinit>(WscompileMessages.java:40)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportOptions.validate(WsimportOptions.java:263)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:120)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.localization.LocalizableMessageFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

It seems, I am not the only person having this issue. Solutions that I found (and used for quite a while, was to use Java 6). Now it seems some update of OSX completly removed Java 6 from my system and I there seems to be no offical download links for Java 6 for OSX anymore.

Is there some way to get this "wsimport" working again for Java 7 or 8?